# Comfortable convertation HTML to NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I would like to have long 'NSString' with this html:

```
<html>

    <head>
       <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    </body>

</html>
```

Is there a comfortable way of doing this? Something like:

```
    NSString *a = [NSString stringWithLongString: "   

<html>

    <head>
       <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    </body>

</html>"]
```

Without having to sqwush everything to one line?

Comment: Consider putting the html text in its own file. You can simply load it with +stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:

Comment: What if I need to change the content of the html constantly?

Comment: @Luda you can add the .html file to Xcode like any other source code file and edit it there. It will even have correct syntax coloring.

Comment: But, I need it to be done on run time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a `\` to the end of every line:

```
NSString *a = @"    <html>\
\
    <head>\
    <title>Title of the document</title>\
    </head>\
\
    <body>\
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>\
    </body>\
\
</html>";
```

There is no need to do a `[NSString stringWithString:]` method, also there is not method `stringWithLongString:` for `NSString`.

Comment: Even if this is correct, putting the html into a file would be much better solution than polluting code by html.

Comment: True, but that is not the question asked by @Luda. I do agree that putting it in a separate file would be beter.

Comment: question asked by @Luda :) And what if I need to change the content of the html constantly?

Answer (score 0):

End each line with a "\"

```
NSString *a = @"    <html>\
\
<head>\
<title>Title of the document</title>\
</head>\
\
<body>\
<h1>My First Heading</h1>\
</body>\
\
</html>";
```

Comment: Are you sure about stringWithLongString?